# Send message to a kafka topic using java

Tags: python, eclipse, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

After several weeks looking for some information here and google, I've decided to post it here to see if anyone with the same problem can raise me a hand.

I have a java application developed in Eclipse Ganymede using tomcat to connect with my local database. The problem is that I want to send a simple message ("Hello World") to a Kafka Topic published on a public server. I've imported the libraries and developed the Kafka function but something happens when I run in debug mode. I have no issues or visible errors when compiling, but when I run the application and push the button to raise this function it stops in KafkaProducer function because there is NoClassDefFoundError kafka.producer..... It seems like it is not finding the library properly, but I have seen that it is in the build path properly imported.

I am not sure if the problem is with Kafka and the compatibility with Eclipse or Java SDK (3.6), it could be?. Anyone knows the minimum required version of Java for Kafka?

Also, I have found that with Kafka is really used Scala but I want to know if I can use this Eclipse IDE version for not change this.

Another solution that I found is to use a Python script called from the Java application, but I have no way to call it from there since I follow several tutorials but then nothing works, but I have to continue on this because it seems an easier option. I have developed the .py script and works with the Kafka server, now I have to found the solution to exchange variables from Java and Python. If anyone knows any good tutorial for this, please, let me know.

After this resume of my days and after hitting my head with the walls, maybe someone has found this error previously and can help me to find the solution, I really appreciate it and sorry for the long history.

Comment: Are alle dependencies of Kafka included via something like Maven (or maybe manually)?

Comment: I added manually from Project Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was related with the library that was not well added. I had to add it in the build.xml file, importing here the library. Maybe this is useful for the people who use an old Eclipse version.
So now it finds the library but I have to update Java version, other matter. So it is solved

Answer (score 0):

Please include the Kafka client library within the WAR file of the Java application which you are deploying to Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Please use org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer rather than kafka.producer.Producer (which is the old client API) and make sure you have the Kafka client library on the classpath. The client library is entirely in Java. It's the old API that's written in scala, as is the server-side code. You don't need to import the server library in your code or add it to the classpath if you use the new client API.